# Install Selenium in Ubuntu 16.04 and check it using java code

Tags: java, selenium

I want to make a java program(GUI) which will **auto-fill the username and password in a website on click of a button**. I am new to networking concepts in java. A friend told to use **selenium** because that will make it easy but I am not able to use it successfully (tried code is shown below). I am using **Ubuntu 16.04** OS and using **gedit** to write the source code. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class pextax implements ActionListener {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button;
.
.
.
public void GUI() throws Exception  {
    button = new JButton("Click to open PEXTAX official website");
    button.addActionListener(this);

.
.
.
}

public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event) {
    if(event.getSource()==button)   {
        try {
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
            capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

            driver.get("https://www.pextax.com");
            driver.manage().window().maximize();

            WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
            WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));

            username.sendKeys("123456789");
            password.sendKeys("1234");

        }catch(Exception e) {   }
    }
  }
}
```

> vivek@vivek-HP-Notebook:~$ javac pextax.java
>
> pextax.java:4: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
>   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
>                             ^
>
> pextax.java:5: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
>   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
>                             ^
>
> pextax.java:6: error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
>   import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
>                             ^
>
> pextax.java:7: error: package org.openqa.selenium.firefox does not exist
>   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
>                                     ^
>
> pextax.java:8: error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
>   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
>                                        ^
>
> pextax.java:9: error: package org.openqa.selenium.support.ui does not exist
>   import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

Comment: Can you please define which type of project is it? is it a maven based project??